# Symfony and Api-Platform: Use Doctrine and other Services outside controllers

Tags: symfony

**Hello Stackoverflow**

We have a problem with Symfony and API-PLATFORM. We tried a lot of things, but couldn't find any solution. We had difficulties using the answers already given on stackoverflow and the git issues they have that are related to this question. This is why this is not a duplicate in any form, since those sadly didn't help us.

The problem is as follows. We have the standard structure in our `src` folder of api-platform.

```
- src
-- Annotation
-- Controller
-- Doctrine
-- Emails
-- Entity
-- EventListener
-- EventSubscriber
-- Filters
-- Repository
-- Security
-- Utils
```

So here is were our problem starts. We have a few classes which are just some utilities for easy use. Those are in the `utils` folder. This question is about a class in the Utils folder named `Phone`. (namespace `App\Utils\Phone`). The thing here is, that we need to use the `EntityManager` in this Utils class, because we need to store some of the data (Temporarily). We'll do this with the following code (Which works in controllers)

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($smsStore);
$em->flush();
```

Now the error hits: Doctrine doesn't even exist here. It cannot be found. The question here is: How can we use the Doctrine EntityManager outside of the Controllers? We tried extending by using the default AbstractController, but this cannot be correct and doesn't work.

The same thing happens when we want to use our security class to get the current user. (`$this->security->getUser()`). Even when we import it like with a use. `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;`.

We hope we were clear with this question. We're a bit desperate because we're still looking for a solution after a few days. We use PHP version `7.1.3` and API-PLATFORM version `1.1` (composer.json)

**EDIT 1:** The does not exist is about an undefined method (getDoctrine). We tried a few things to implement this. For example using the AbstractController to extend the class. Another solution that worked is really pass the DoctrineManager with the function. This is however not a good practice.

**EDIT 2:** The AuthController snippet as requested. It shows how we use the Phone Utils. Could it be that I need to implement the EntityInterface at this function surrounding the following code?

```
    $phone = new Phone();
    $phone->overwriteUser($this->getUser());

    $phone->newRecipient("4917640733908");
    $phone->setBody("Hello, this is a test.");
```

Comment: Please forgive me, I'm not sure to understand your question. Do you want to be able to use/call the entityManager in your Utils classes?

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant Exactly! But I don't know how.

Comment: "Doesn't exist" sounds strange. Why not use the standard ways to "make it exist"? What have you tried so far about this, where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase The problem is that it can't find any Interfaces. I tried the standards ways to make it exists, like I said in my answer. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't find"? Can you share your attempts? Additionally, please remove unneccessary tags, as autowiring issues are not connected to Doctrine or API platform

Comment: @NicoHaase We've tried including the AbstractController (As said), and we tried something like the answer below. This does not work. Sorry if I was unclear about the error. It says that getDoctrine is undefined. Even when trying the ways to get it defined (For examle as shown below). I've updated the tags.

Comment: In your snippet, you are doing this `$phone = new Phone`, it is exactly what you do NOT have to do. $phone shall be an argument of the method, it shall NOT be manually created :). Look at the last snippet of my answer.

Comment: You haven't posted any code snippets, so it is a bit hard to reconstruct where your code is missing something.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not fluent in english. Reload the page, look at the last code lines of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity manager could be handle with the dependency injection(DI) pattern. [This pattern is fully integrated in Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html). This is the fun and magic aspect of Symfony.

All classes implementing an interface are available with dependency injections. With Symfony4+, the autoconfigure is activated. It seems to be complex, but for the final developer, it's pretty easy. Here is a simple example to do it with your Phone classes which seems to be a model where you have implemented you business logic.

```
class Phone
{
    private $entityManager;

    //The entity manager will be provided to your constructor with the dependency injection.
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
       $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function save($smsStore)
    {
       //you own logic go here

       //here is the magic part, the entityManager is available, connected, ready to use. 
       $this->entityManager->persist($smsStore);
       $em->flush();
    }
}
```

When you'll call the Utils classes method, the DI will construct it automatically and you will be able to use its property, the entity manager in this case.

If you want to use you class in a controller, you can do it by adding the phone class in its constructor:

```php
class AuthController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(Phone $phoneUtils)
    {      
       $this->phoneUtils = $phoneUtils;
    }

    public function someAction()
    {
       //your own logic here

       //here is the magic part, the phone Utils is ready, it imports the entitymanager
       //when you want to save your smsStore, simply call it
       $this->phoneUtils->save($smsStore);
    }
}
```

You are using Api-Platform, no problem! You can reproduce this design pattern in other classes like your DataPersisters, or in your EventListeners. If you look at this [example in the ApiPlateform documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/#custom-event-listeners), you can see how author get the Swiftmailer manager in his event listener. Simply replace the swiftmailer by EntityManagerInterface or the Phone utils classes.

(In a controller, it exists a simpliest way to retrieve the phone utils class)

```php
class AuthController extends AbstractController
{
    //Do That: ADD Phone $phoneUtils as an argument in the method
    public function someAction(Phone $phoneUtils)
    {
       //your own logic here
       //Do not do that: $phoneUtils = new Phone();

       //Magic! when you want to save your smsStore, simply call it
       $phoneUtils->save($smsStore);
    }
}
```

If you want to get an autowired class (like the security layer), you could do it. To find which classes could be autowired, there are some tips:

```
symfony console debug:autowiring
symfony console debug:autowiring Security
symfony console debug:autowiring AuthorizationChecker
```

It will return all the classes corresponding to your search.

(If you do not use the symfony executable, you could replace it by php bin/console debug:autowiring)

Comment: Hey, your answer is great. We do know how to use the class, the issue is that we can't use the EntityManager. However, we tried something like your answer already. I've constructed it like your answer and the response was an error. It wants me to pass the EntityManagerInterface when I use it.

`Too few arguments to function App\Utils\Phone\Phone::__construct(), 0 passed in /srv/api/src/Controller/AuthController.php on line 49 and exactly 1 expected` (The AuthController is where I use the code)

Comment: I've updated my question to provide you with the snippet.

Comment: Okay, when I do it your way it allows me to use the `EntityManagerInterface`. That's a great help. However ,it still does not see getDoctrine as defined. Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "App\Utils\Phone\Phone".` Do I need to call a save on the util? Since this would be a part of sending a sms with `$phone->sms()'. Could it be that I still miss a required autowired class?

Comment: My bad, there is a big mistake in my code !!! I edited it !  Now the code will work. Because of DI, you do not have to call the getDoctrine() method, sorry. (I only removed one line of code)

Comment: You are amazing. It did in fact solve my issue. I will mark your answer als solution. However I do have a relevant question I also asked in my first post. How can I implement the Security component in the phone class? Does this also function the same way? Now that I call it like you do, this should be possible right?

Comment: Since I do not know which component you're looking for (there are a lot in the Security layer), I add some lines to explain how to find available components with autowiring.